# Distribution of the square of the biased inner product of two normal random vectors

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $[x_1,\dots,x_n]^{\top}=\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a random vector whose elements are sampled independently from a normal distribution with zero mean and unit standard deviation, i.e., $x_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ for $i=1,\dots,n$. Let $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be another random vector whose elements are sampled independently from a normal distribution with zero mean and unit standard deviation, i.e., $a_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ for $i=1,\dots,n$. Also assume elements of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{a}$ are independent of each other. Assume we randomly set $r$ elements of $\mathbf{x}$ and then calculate $y=(\mathbf{x}^{\top}\mathbf{a}-b)^2$ where $b \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is independent of elements of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{a}$.

**Question**

Does $y$ follow a known distribution? What is the expectation of $y$?

**My try**

Without loss of generality suppose we keep the first $r$ elements of $\mathbf{x}$. Then $y=(\sum_
{i=1}^rx_ia_i-b)^2=\sum_
{i=1}^r\Big((x_ia_i)^2-2(x_ia_i)b\Big)+b^2$.

Comment: What do you mean by randomly set? Is $r$ random? If it isn't, then $r = n$ loses no generality. You have products of independent normals, which is  known distribution. Then you take sums of them ... which might be known?

Comment: @Mason: $r$ is known. You are right, what would be the distribution though?